# class public variable calls compatible in PHP 7.0 and PHP 5.6

Tags: php, class, public, php-7

**In PHP 5.6:**

When being inside a class we usually declare & call a public class variable like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $myVar = 0;

    // call it in a public function:
   public function myFunction()
   {
       return $this->myVar;
   }

}
```

I call the function like this:

```
MyClass::myFunction();
```

**In PHP 7.0 that code throws a fatal error:**

> Using $this when not in object context

After changing my PHP version back to 5.6 again, the error was gone.

**Questions:**

*I have to admit that after reading the manual and changes from 5.6 to 7.0 I don't get it.*

1. How do we declare and call public class variables in PHP 7.0?
2. How do we write this code to be compatible between 5.6 and 7.0?

**Edit after comments:**

So why then a static call on a non static method works in 5.6?

Comment: How are you calling the function? That's important.

Comment: I'm rather sure you're analyzing the error incorrectly. The code you are showing is fine. I agree with the above that it is the calling of said method that is the cause.

Comment: Added the function call

Comment: It's not a static function, and if it was. Your variable is not static.

Comment: Ok I get it now, but why this works in 5.6?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php - Static calls to non-static methods

Comment: I've just tested in both, php5 and php7. There is no difference in behavior.

Comment: It doesn't work as you want in 5.6, but you're probably suppressing the messages in your 5.6... 7 has made the messages stricter [Demo](https://3v4l.org/cvgP2)

Comment: I've setup a test case, where this fatal error occurs. This is when you already are in a $this context.

Comment: @MarkBaker Try out my example below. It throws a fatal error in 7 but not even a warning in 5.

Comment: Not even a warning?!? 5.6 gives `Deprecated: Non-static method MyClass::myFunction() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /in/T4Qbm on line 26
2` and 5.5 gives `Strict Standards: Non-static method MyClass::myFunction() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /in/T4Qbm on line 26
2` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/T4Qbm)

Comment: @MarkBaker Check, in my CLI version error reporting had become disabled for some reason, probably due to an update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In I'm loading maybe
>   func() like this:

```
 obj::func();  // Wrong, it is not static method
```

> but can also be

```
$obj = new Obj();  // correct
$obj->func();
```

You can not invoke method this way because it is not static method.

```
obj::func();
```

You should instead use:

```
obj->func();
```

If however you have created a static method something like:

```
static $foo; // your top variable set as static

public static function foo() {
    return self::$foo;
}
```

then you can use this:

```
obj::func();
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe can be found in the following example:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
  /**
   * @var int
   */
  public $myVar = 1;

  // call it in a public function:
  public function myFunction()
  {
    return $this->myVar;
  }    
}

class MyClass2
{
  /**
   * @var int
   */
  public $myVar = 2;

  public function test()
  {
    echo MyClass::myFunction();
    // outputs: 2
  }
}


$obj = new MyClass2();
$obj->test();
?>
```

In PHP 5 you can call a public method of other classes, when you are inside an instance. It will work as it was a member of the class in the current $this context. PHP 7 is more stict. You can extend classes or import traits into classes in different inheritance lines. There is no need to steel other classes' methods. You can still use the `Classname::method()` or `parent::method()` syntax to call ancestor's methods.

Answer (score 0):

You accomplish the same by instantiating object of that class and then call that class's method.

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $myVar = 0;

    // call it in a public function:
   public function myFunction()
   {
       return $this->myVar;
   }

}
$obj = new Myclass();
$result = $obj->myFunction();
print $result;
```